# How can I pass dynamically created checkboxes in a module to com_ajax?

Tags: ajax

I have a frontend module with this php file under tmpl folder. It fills with joomla's published categories and shows a checkbox for each one, based on current registered user preferences from a table:

```
<div class="userfavcats<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx ?>">
<div class="row-striped">
    <?php foreach ($list as $item) : ?>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            <strong class="row-title">
             <?php echo $item->name; ?>               
            </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="data" value="<?php echo $item->id; ?>" <?php if($item->selected) echo(" checked ");?>/>        
        </div>          
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</div>
```

The idea is to allow the user to check/uncheck categories and send that new selection to the module and save it back to the DB. I haves the following code in my **mod_userfavcats** module, based on helloworld com_ajax sample.
The problem is that don´t know how to obtain each checked value as an array, for example.

```
(function ($) {
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function () {
    var value   = $('input[name=data]').val(),
        request = {
                'option' : 'com_ajax',
                'module' : 'userfavcats',
                'data'   : value,
                'format' : 'raw' 
            };
    $.ajax({
        type   : 'POST',
        data   : request,
        success: function (response) {
            $('.status').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

})(jQuery)

thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a JQuery, you can find checkboxes and return checked property. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/checking-a-checkbox-with-jquery